# Embedded font in mx-AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer not working

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, embedding, advanceddatagrid, flex-mx

I'm facing here really annoying issue when trying to embed custom font in AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer.

After some research I found this solution: http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2011/01/20/getting-spark-mx-components-to-use-embedded-fonts/.

Somehow, and I guess it's because I'm using custom mx AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer, which overrids the fontFamily styling property, and I cannot see the embedded font.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to share some code?  What is your itemRenderer?  What ist he code for your embedded font?  How are the two associated with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured....

First of all some sharing, 
In order to embed my custom font for spark as well for mx components I used:

```
s|global
    {
        fontFamily: [MY_CUSTOM_FONT];
        fontSize: 14;
        textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETextField");
    }
```

This is works for most  mx components.

Now, we are using mx components **AdvancedDatagrid** and **AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer** (not ***MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer*** Which is actually a spark component).

In that case I had to change my **CustomAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer** to extends **FTEAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer** instead of just **AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer**.

Which solve the problem! Hurrah!